# Setting scroll bar always at bottom

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am building a chat app in vue and I want my scroll bar to always be at the bottom. I only used overflow: auto; and coded custom scroll bar. And every time I send a message, the scroll bar won't get to the bottom. Any help in vue js

```
<v-card
     fluid
    style="overflow: auto; ">
</v-card>
```

and the CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ccc;  
}
    enter code here
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
   background: #999;  
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case.
You can do that like below:

```
 <div v-for="(message, index) in messages" :key="index">
    <v-card :id="message.id" >
      {{ message.text }}
    </v-card>
  </div>


  watch: {
// scroll to end when message send or select another chat
messages: async function () {
    await this.scrollToEnd();
},
```

methods:

```
 async scrollToEnd() {
  try {
    if (this.messages && this.messages.length > 0) {
      const id = await this.messages[this.messages.length-1].id; 
     document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView({ block: "start" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
},
```